# Azure SignalR Service - Multiple Server Configurations

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-signalr

When implementing Azure Application Services that implement a SignalR Hub, is it possible to determine which Application Services should be included in the pool of available Servers when establishing a client connection?

Example:

We have one Azure SignalR service hosting one SignalR Hub.  We then reference an implementation of that SignalR Hub in TWO DIFFERENT Web Apis (FunApi1, FunApi2).  The overall functionality of these Apis is not guaranteed to be the same.

Upon the connection of a client, when Azure SignalR establishes a persistent connection to a Hub Server, is it possible to ensure that all clients connect ONLY to FunApi1?

Is there any documentation on how the service chooses servers (round-robin, etc)?  Is it simply an unsupported use case?